# How to remove a particular character after a specific word

Tags: text-processing

How do I remove the `,` character after a specific word?

For example, I want to delete the `,` character after the word `IBM`

```
  IBM, Inc.:APP-VM-Core:4.4.2.0:04,
```

the expected results should be

```
  IBM Inc.:APP-VM-Core:4.4.2.0:04,
```

Meanwhile I do the following

```
   echo “IBM, Inc.:APP-VM-Core:4.4.2.0:04,” | sed s'/,//'
```

but the problem is that it deletes every `,` character, no matter what the first word was before the `,`. In my case I want to delete the `,` only after `IBM`.

Example:

```
echo "APPLE, Inc.:APP-VM-Core:4.4.2.0:04,"| sed s'/,//'

APPLE Inc.:APP-VM-Core:4.4.2.0:04,
```

but should be as

```
APPLE, Inc.:APP-VM-Core:4.4.2.0:04,
```

Comment: You can do it using `awk`.  For example:  `echo IBM, Inc.:APP-VM-Core:4.4.2.0:04, | awk '/IBM/{sub(/,/,"")}1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ echo "IBM, Inc.:APP-VM-Core:4.4.2.0:04," | sed '/^ *IBM/s/,//'
IBM Inc.:APP-VM-Core:4.4.2.0:04,
```

or:

```
$ echo "IBM, Inc.:APP-VM-Core:4.4.2.0:04," | sed 's/^\( *IBM\),/\1/'
IBM Inc.:APP-VM-Core:4.4.2.0:04,
```

Comment: what in case we have spaces between begin of line to IBM

Comment: @maihabunash: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to modify a file you'd rather use `ex` or `ed` but definitely not `sed`.  Why not `sed`?

`sed` is a `S`tream `ED`itor and you'd modify the data coming from a stream with it.

Using `ex` you could do the following

`ex -sc '%s/IBM,/IBM/g|x' file`   wheren `file` is your filename.

As alternative. If you want to remove leading **spaces** or **tabs** you will need more than `^ *`. For example. The solution would be using `awk` as follow:

```
awk '{sub(/^[ \t]+IBM,/,"IBM");};1' input_file > output_file
```

or

```
awk '{sub(/^[[:blank:]]*IBM,/,"IBM");};1' input_file > output_file
```

Mind you. `^ *` will not be able to detect **tabs**.

You also can use `ex` as explained earlier but now including the regular expression to match only the line beginning with spaces and including the pattern **IBM**

```
ex -sc '%s/^[[:blank:]]*IBM,/IBM/g|x' input_file
```

Comment: To those who are downvoting the answer. Please write a comment at least to demonstrate the flaws in the answer. This way we all can provide better answers in the future. It could help me a lot to improve my writing and or explanation!  Thanks!